# Maximum value of norm of mass matrix M

Tags: robotic-arm, kinematics, dynamics

How do I compute the maximum values for ||M(q)|| and ||M_dot(q)||, the induced 2-norms, where M(q) is the mass matrix from the standard dynamical model of a robotic manipulator. I have the numerical values but not the analytical symbolic representation.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an eigenvalue problem because:

1. The [mass matrix can be assumed to be PSD](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/95742)
2. The induced norm of a PSD matrix is [see here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/53291/45320) $\sqrt{\lambda_{max}(A^TA)}$

So for anything but the smallest matrices, you should use iterative methods to determine the norm (i.e., there is no closed-form solution).